# Replacement for sun.misc.Hashing

Tags: scala, hash

My scala program broke because the Hashing object is no longer in the sun.misc package. Can anyone recommend a replacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala contains its own implementation of the MurmurHash 3 algorithm, though I don't know if it's the same revision as the `sun.misc.Hashing` implementation.

It's in `scala.util.hashing.MurmurHash3`.